# Share a dictionary between GPU and CPU in Pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, gpu

I use torch to build a model. In the training loop, I need to compute a dictionary of values which will happen on GPU. Then, every few iterations, I need to use the dictionary which was on GPU to perform some other tasks on CPU. So there is a back and forth between the two. Currently, I use `torch.save` and `torch.load` to save and load the said dictionary which is very slow and not thread-safe.

I am almost sure that there is a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do. I understand that copying data to/from GPU causes slowdown but I am looking for a strategy that does not involve the disk.

Comment: I imagine that you don't want to stop the training loop. So naively calling .to("cpu") and blocking the training loop is quite not what you want. Instead, maybe deepcopying the dictionnary then pushing it in the thread (if I understand your problem correctly) and finally bring it back on cpu may be a solution ?